# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot x^n=0$ why do we need $a_0=a_1=a_2=......=0$? prove it

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

To have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cdot x^n=0$$
for all $x$, we need $a_0=a_1=a_2=......=0$

I don't quite see the logic here, why only $(0,0,0,......)$ can satisfy this?

**Proof by contradiction:**

Suppose $a_i\neq 0$

But then we can say nothing about other coefficients...

Or if we assume $a_{i\neq i}=0$ then for $x=1$, then for $x=1$ this is not $0$. But this is only a special case...

**or we can solve the linear system**

$$1,1,1,1,.......$$

$$1,2,4,8,.......$$

$$1,3,9,27,......$$

$$...$$

$$...$$

Answer (score 5):

Assume otherwise and let $n$ be the smallest index with $a_n \neq 0$. Then you can write the series as $x^n g(x)$, where $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{n+k} x^k$ is non-zero near $x = 0$ (since $g(0) = a_n \neq 0$ and $g$ is continuous near $0$). This shows that $x = 0$ is the only zero of $x^n g(x)$ near $x = 0$, which contradicts the assumption.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = 0$ is an analytic function, hence the only valid power series representation is the Taylor series at $x=0$. In particular, we have $a_n = \frac{ f^{(n)} (0) }{n!} = 0$ for all $n$.

---

We can also prove it using the following theorem:

Let $E$ be the set of all $S$ at which

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n.$$

If $E$ has a limit point in $S$, then $a_n = b_n $ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$.

Here we have the $b_n = 0$ for all $n$, and they are equal in $S = \mathbb{R}$, so $a_n = 0$ for all $n$ a swell.

Comment: Could you please further explain. Why the only valid one is the Taylor series

Comment: It's a theorem that if $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ is smooth, then we must have $a_n$ is equal to the Taylor series coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

If the series converges for all real $x$, the sum is an entire function.  The generalized Cauchy integral formula then shows that the coefficients are all $0$.

Comment: But we do not guarantee it converge for all real x. For example in solving ODEs

Comment: Perhaps just some radius around 0

Comment: @bastarf In that case, consider where it is differentiable and take derivatives. Assuming $x=0$ is in the domain where it converges, plug in $x=0$ and you'll get that the coefficients are all zero.

Comment: Also the use of Cauchy integral formula... Can be more specific?

Comment: @CameronWilliams plug in x=0 I only get a_0=0

Comment: @bastarf That's why I suggested taking derivatives.

Comment: If "we do not guarantee it converge for all real $x$", why did you say "for all $x$" in the original problem?

Comment: If it converges anywhere, it has nonzero radius of convergence, which is all you need.

Comment: Cauchy formula finds the coefficients using contour integrals.